# Dynamically create predicate with AND/OR?

Tags: linq

I have a method that creates a predicate based on the data from several fields. The fields can contain comma separated values. I can create a predicate that will *OR* the values in the field but then I need to *AND* the fields together.

```
    if (model.MICA != null)
        {
            List<string> ids = ParseCSVList(model.MICA); 
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(m =>  m.idtype == "MICA" && m.idnumber.Contains(id));
            }
        }
** I need to AND these two records together**
        if (model.FRID != null)
        {
            List<string> ids = ParseCSVList(model.FRID);
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(e => e.idtype == "FRID" && e.idnumber.Contains(id));
            }
        }
```

When building a predicate is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using predicate.And?